# while passing to a function in Prime31 throws error in ios in unity3d project

Tags: c#, error-handling, unity-game-engine, prime31

I have to use a function in Prime31 for requestiong product data in ios. The function is

```
var iosProductIds = new string[] { "com.something.dollar"};

IAP.requestProductData( iosProductIds, androidSkus, productList =>
{
  Debug.Log( "Product list received" );
  Utils.logObject( productList );
});
```

its working fine.

But if i extract a value from array named **"pArray"** and declared it as a variable

```
var pid = pArray [0];
```

and passing to function as

```
string[] stringArray = new string[1];
stringArray[0] =pid ;
var iosProductIds = stringArray;
```

throws error **"StoreKit: invalid productIdentifier: com.something.dollar"** .

I tried

```
string pid = pArray [0];
```

also. But stucked with same error.

How can i clear it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string pid = pArray [0]; 
string[] stringArray = new string[1];
stringArray[0] = pid.Trim();
var iosProductIds = stringArray;
```

works fine.